# How do I make a python class satisfying an interface in SWIG?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'd like to make an object in Python that sastifies a C++ instance using SWIG.

Given I have an example like `Example.h`:

```
struct iCat
{
    virtual int paws() const = 0;
};

int pawGiver(const iCat& cat);

struct cat : public iCat
{
    int paws() const
    {
        return 4;
    }
};
```

And `Example.cpp`:

```
#include "Example.h"
int pawGiver(const iCat& cat)
{
    return cat.paws();
}
```

And `example.i`:

```
/* File : example.i */
%module example
%{
#include "Example.h"
%}
%include "Example.h"
```

The above, of course, compile fine. I wrote the below to try to make an `iCat` in Python, i.e.:

```
import example;
class pyCat(example.iCat):
     def __init__(self):
             super().__init__()
     def paws(self):
             return 3;

z = pyCat()
example.pawGiver(z)
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Can a Python class fulfill a C++ instance? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error you do get when you try to run the code?

Comment: I don't think you can do what you are trying to do because the C++ class is an abstract base class. I will wait for somebody more knowledgeable than I to prove me wrong.

Comment: Right but my class fulfills the interface

Comment: You get `AttributeError: No constructor defined - class is abstract` if you include `(example.iCat)`, if you drop it, you get `TypeError: in method 'pawGiver', argument 1 of type 'iCat const &'`

Comment: @Carbon, I understand the motivation and the expectation. I don't think SWIG can generate all the intermediate code to make sure that `pyCat` is instantiable. But then, I am speculating a bit here.

Comment: GOT IT! Modify to `%module(directors="1") example` and add `%feature("director");`

Comment: @Carbon, add the solution as an answer.

Comment: @Carbon Did you try `%feature("notabstract")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is easy. Modify the interface to:

```
/* File : example.i */
%module(directors="1") example
%{
#include "Example.h"
%}
%feature("director");
%include "Example.h"
```

Runs fine.

Comment: Nice catch! here's the link to the official [http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Go_director_enable](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Go_director_enable). Both question and answer really interesting ones, so, there we go, +2 ;)